# Azure Functions crashing loading MongoDB in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-functions

I'm attempting to write an Azure Function, in Node, to connect into a MongoDB instance (Cosmos DB in this case).

However, as soon I run `require("mongodb")`, my function crashes, without throwing an error, or logging anything, with the HTTP response returning a `502` code.

My setup:

- Creating a function app using all defaults through the Azure portal.
- Creating a `package.json` with `mongodb` version `3.x`.
- Running `npm install` through the Kudu shell
- Include the require statement in my code.
- Make a request to the function

This doesn't throw an error in the code, and I see logging that's run before, but not after the require statement (which is making it pretty difficult to debug).

I've also tried following through [this guide](http://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-azure-functions-and-mongodb.html) about running a mongo query from a function, and it fails in exactly the same way for me.

After putting some hooks into Node's `module` module, my attempts to debug this led to a line in one of mongo's dependencies that fails in a similar way when run in isolation ([from saslprep](https://github.com/reklatsmasters/saslprep/blob/master/lib/code-points.js#L405)), which seems to stem from running out of stack space.

However, this feels like its a pretty mainstream use for an Azure function, and I haven't seen any similar issues, so I'm inclined to suspect that its an issue with my setup, rather than the `mongodb` library, but I haven't been able to find a misconfiguration, as I haven't changed any defaults - right now, I'm stumped!

I don't have a full code example right now, as I'm away from my work computer, but the code is something like

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
module.exports = function(context) {
  context.res = {
    body: 'Hello world'
  };

  context.done();
}
```

Without the require statement, the code runs fine, returning the response to the browser.

Comment: have you got any more details from your node web app?

Comment: The function is just the default webhook JavaScript function, with `require("mongodb")` put in at the top - Sorry, I'm away from my work computer right now, so I can't provide a full example.

Comment: The module might not be installed on Functions by default and you may have to install it manually. Have you checked that there is a node_modules directory in your function app's file structure? Also, which version of Functions are you running on, v1 or v2? (Check the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION app setting - "beta" is v1.)

Comment: @KatyShimizu - It isn't installed by default (I installed it using the kudu shell), I've verified installed in the node_modules directory. I'm running on v2 of Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this problem was caused by running out of stack space. After pushing a patch to the saslprep library (v1.0.1), this has now been fixed.

Comment: Can you provide detail how you pushed a patch to the saslprep library? I have attempted to upgrade mongo but I keep getting saslprep v1.0.0. I am having the exact same problem as you.

Comment: I think your problem can be fixed by deleting your `package-lock.json` file and reinstalling, it may be preventing you from getting the new version. (If that doesn&#39;t work, try also deleting your `node-modules` folder and reinstalling from scratch.)

I made a pull request to the GitHub page, which the author accepted and published as v1.0.1 (I really do have to thank him for being great to work with).

Comment: I completely forgot about `package-lock.json`. Nuking that file and `node_modules` allowed me to get saslprep 1.0.1. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that if you add to your require function the same as in Microsofts Cosmos DB guides for mongo the following it should work

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

you have it as:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
```

Im curious to know if that makes a difference. After looking through Microsofts own docs nearly all of them are declared that way.

Here is the tutorial I found:  [MongoDB app using Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-samples)

Comment: I'm afraid I've tried that - it yields exactly the same result. The problem seems to happen while loading the dependency, so trying to access a property from the dependency doesn't seem to solve it.